# Incorrect metrics and sizes of font created by CreateFont()

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, rendering

I trying to render a font into bitmap using WinAPI, but I can't reach needed sizes of font.

Here's how the font is initialized:

```
HDC dc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
::SetMapMode(dc, MM_TEXT);
::SetTextAlign(dc, TA_LEFT | TA_TOP | TA_UPDATECP);
int size_in_pixels = 18;
HFONT font = ::CreateFontA(-size_in_pixels, ..., "Arial");
::SelectObject(dc, font);
::TEXTMETRICW tm = { 0 };
GetTextMetricsW(dc, &tm);
```

But after it I getting incorrect values both in `GetGlyphOutlineW` and `GetTextMetricsW`, it's not size I passed as parameter
I know that it's expecting value in logical units, but in MM_TEXT 1 unit should be 1 pixel, don't it?

I expecting that `CreateFontA` accepting point size when I passing a negative value (like here https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEt8J.png), but in fact it's wrong.
I tried bruteforcing values, and find out proper parameter for a few sizes:

```
18px = -19; 36px = -39; 73px = -78;
```

Also I tried formula that provided by Microsoft:

```
nHeight = -MulDiv(PointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
```

But it's also giving me a wrong result, rendered text (using `GetGlyphOutlineW`) is larger if measure it (for example height of 'j' should have exact size that I passed)
Also metrics from `GetTextMetricsW` are wrong, for example `tmAscent`. I know that on Windows it's including internal leading, but even if subtract `tmInternalLeading` from `tmAscent` it's still incorrect.
By the way, values from `GetCharABCWidthsW` are correct, so a+b+c is width of glyph in pixels (while documentation says it should be in logical units).

Also I should say about DPI, usually I using 125% on Windows 10 scale in settings, but I tried even with 100%, interesting that `::GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSY)` not changing with scale I using, it's always 96

Here's example of `CreateFontA(-128, ...)` with final atlas and metrics:
[rendered atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UcQ3.png)

Question #1: What should I do to pass wanted point size in pixels and receive glyphs in proper size with correct metrics in pixels?

Question #2: What the strange units all these functions are using?

Comment: [MM_TEXT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2113574-0d22-4424-ae3a-6b1999100a32/gdi-logical-units?forum=vcgeneral)：Each logical unit is mapped to one device pixel. Why DPI always 96, because you didn't set the default DPI perception of the process to system DPI perception.See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware).You'd better provide more code to illustrate the problem. Sometimes one line of code is more effective than ten sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `::SetMapMode(dc, MM_TEXT);` the font size is specified in device pixels. Negative value excludes internal leading, so for the same absolute value the negative ones produce visually bigger fonts. If you want to get same height from `GetTextExtentPoint32` for different fonts, use positive values.

In your example with `-128` height, you are requesting font for which, after internal leading exclusion, height is 128 pixels. Font mapper selects `143` which is correct for internal leading of `15` pixels (128+15=143). `tmAscent` + `tmDescent` are also correct (115+28=143). You get what you specified.

You should take into account that values in text metric don't state hard bounds. Designer can design fonts so its glyphs sometimes go beyond guiding lines or don't reach them.

> for example height of 'j' should have exact size that I passed

Dot over `j` can go beyond or not reach top line if designer finds it visually plausible to design it that way.

> interesting that `::GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSY)` not changing with scale I using, it's always 96

Unless you log off and log in, system DPI doesn't change. For per monitor DPI aware application you have to get DPI from monitor parameters or cache value given by `WM_DPICHANGED`.

> Question #1: What should I do to pass wanted point size in pixels and receive glyphs in proper size with correct metrics in pixels?

I think you want to get specific distance between top and bottom lines and this is exactly how you create font `HFONT font = ::CreateFontA(-size_in_pixels, ..., "Arial");`. The problem lies in your assumption that font design lines are hard boundaries for each glyph, but font's designer don't have to strictly align glyphs to these lines. If you want glyphs strictly aligned, probably there is no way to get it. Maybe check different font.

> Question #2: What the strange units all these functions are using?

When mode is set to `WM_TEXT`, raw device pixels are used. Positive height specifies height including `tmInternalLeading`, negative excludes it.

For positive value:
`tmAscent + tmDescent = requestedHeight`
For negative value:
`tmAscent + tmDescent - tmInternalLeading = requestedHeight`

Bellow I have pasted screen shots with different fonts showing that depending on selected font glyphs could be designed so they don't reach top line or go beyond it and bottom line in most cases also isn't reached.

Seems that for your requirements Arial Unicode MS would be better fit (but j still doesn't reach where you want it).

Arial:
[image]

Arial Unicode MS
[image]

Input Mono
[image]

Trebuched MS
[image]

Comment: Thank you for an answer! Since it is in pixels, it's okay for me. Difference I saw was caused by a different fonts. I thought that it's the same one, but "Arial" for ethalon renderer was loaded exactly from file (it's ver. 3.0), while "Arial" for CreateFontA was loaded from system (it's ver. 7.0) even if I added it as resource. Anyway your post answered many questions, thank you again.